# Python: Split Integers and Strings in Lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

```
>>>list = []
>>>stringsandnumbers = input('Enter in the values. For example, "A=3,B=2,C=1,D=5"... ').split(',')
>>>list.append(stringsandnumbers)
>>>list.sort()
>>>print(list)

[[A=3,B=2,C=1,D=5]]
```

The problem with this is that it is not sorting the list from min to max. I'm not sure if splitting/separating it would be a good idea or if there's a way to just sort the numbers from the list? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You appear to be creating a list with a single string in it - how do you expect to sort that?! You will need to **parse the input** into some usable format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
>>> s = "A=3,B=2,C=1,D=5"
>>> sorted(s.split(','), key = lambda m: int(m.split('=')[1]))
['C=1', 'B=2', 'A=3', 'D=5']
>>> ','.join(sorted(s.split(','), key = lambda m: int(m.split('=')[1])))
'C=1,B=2,A=3,D=5'
```

Comment: This is what I get:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: you could apply the split function only on string not in list.